# Mongoose JS - Preventing Duplicates in Array of ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using ObjectIds to form relationships between 2 collections in a MongoDB, see below:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

    username: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    password: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    concerts:[
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Concert", unique: true, required: false   
        }
    ]

})
```

```
const concertSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: String, unique: false, required: false},
    concertId: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false },
    artist: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    venue: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    date: { type: Date, unique: false, required: false },
    time: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    city: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
    latitude: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false },
    longitude: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false },
    attendees: [
        {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User", unique: true, required: false    
        }
]

})
```

However, I am running into the problem off duplicate ObjectId's within my database, below is the segment of code where I add ObjectId's to the database:

```
then(show => {
            return db.User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    "_id": req.body.userId
                }, {
                    $push: {concerts: show._id}
                }, {
                    new: true
                }
            ).then(res.json(show))
        })
            }
        else {
            return db.User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                "_id": req.body.userId
            }, {
                $push: {concerts: concert._id}
            }, {
                new: true
            })
            .then(res.json(concert))
        }
        })
```

I have tried $addToSet but it is my understanding that this doesn't work with objects.

Answer (score 0):

`$addToSet` doesn't work with objects, but it will work with `ObjectIds` (because they're essentially just special strings)

```
> db.test_coll.insert({})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test_coll.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$addToSet: {ids: ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630") }}, {returnNewDocument: true});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6b69a6f5b3e45884d12632"),
    "ids" : [
        ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630")
    ]
}
> db.test_coll.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$addToSet: {ids: ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630") }}, {returnNewDocument: true});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6b69a6f5b3e45884d12632"),
    "ids" : [
        ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630")
    ]
}
> db.test_coll.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$addToSet: {ids: ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630") }}, {returnNewDocument: true});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6b69a6f5b3e45884d12632"),
    "ids" : [
        ObjectId("5c6b6714f5b3e45884d12630")
    ]
}
```

Comment: The how would I implement that in my code above? show._id and concert._id but result in ObjectIds in the database but when I do ```{$addToSet: {concerts: concert._id}}``` and ```{$addToSet: {concerts: show._id}}``` I still get duplicates.

Comment: What version of mongo are you on? Could you please add a pastebin with a reproducible error?